# Facebook Insecure Login Blocked on a server with https enabled

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a Node/Express app running on a server with https enabled but when trying to login with Facebook using Passport Facebook strategy, I get this error:

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to
>   this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

I understand Facebook requires authentication but my server already has it. 
The certificate is from LetsEncrypt and since I'm using a managed server, I don't have access to the certificate files. My Express app is initialized normally.

```
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
```

The original request comes from my frontend running on a different server, also with SSL from LetsEncrypt.

So my front end calls the Express endpoint, which handles it to Passport:

```
  app.get(
    "/api/auth/facebook",
    storeRedirectToInSession,
    passport.authenticate("facebook", { scope: ["public_profile", "email"] })
  );
```

And then the error occurs.
My research indicated that enabling "trust proxy" on Express should fix it but it didn't. If I inspect req.secure it's always false.

Do I really need to have access to the certificate files?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To make this easier to read, could you include the full URLs that you are using?

Comment: Here it is @josh

Comment: The website is in Portuguese, but here are the URLS:
frontend: https://assina.ai/ (click on "Entrar" on top), then choose Facebook.

Comment: Just a guess, but that takes me to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbackend.assina.ai%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&client_id=255530375289637`. Something is causing `http` to be in there — maybe you can debug this fully and answer it yourself.

Comment: Well I knew that already. It’s the title of my post. I tried to debug it already and explained my findings on my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People of the future, I could not fix this issue without actually getting access to the cert files on my Node/Express app. I had support create symbolic links to the letsencrypt key and cert files, and then created a https express server as follows:

```
https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync(keys.SSL_KEY_FILE),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(keys.SSL_CERT_FILE),
    },
    app
  )
  .listen(port, function() {
    console.log("ackend server listening on port ", port);
  });
```